# How do I see the commit description in svn?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I'm using Apache Subversion for the first time with Visual Studio + AnkhSVN plug-in. I'm using it alone, just for me to test it. If I commit a new update, there is always a field where I can describe my changes (commit message). I thought that's a good idea, because I can always protocol the stuff I did there. But somehow I never see this text anywhere. So this protocol doesn't make any sense? Or how can I see this?

Comment: JFYI: you don't commit an "update", you commit a "revision".

Comment: @bahrep I thought I commit every change on my code... thats how it should be?

Comment: See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.revs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commit message will be stored in the subversion repository - you need to look at the commit log to see it.

This can be seen when you right-click a file, Subversion -> View History.

Answer (score 1):

**What is log (commit) message?** Log message is a human-readable description of the committed changes stored alongside those changes in the repository.

I.e. with a command-line you can always view the repository log and log messages associated with each revision: [`svn log URL[@REV] [PATH...]`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/log/)

I advise you to check the SVNBook article ["Basic Work Cycle"](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/tour/cycle/). It describes the basic workflow with Apache Subversion and your question is covered there. Don't be afraid of the command-line in the article -- it will provide you with good understanding of what you are actually doing.